# Wordpress translate date

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm doing a Worpress plugin and i searched all codes here and on Wordpress but found nothing to translate the date from RSS fetch from simplepie in the Wordpress core.

I can get the item date this way:
`$item->get_date('F j, Y - g:i a');`
I tried with `date_i18n()` and many way from the [WP core website](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) but nothing work.

Comment: Check the examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php and here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get_local_date function of simplepie: http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_local_date. It returns the date according to the current locale.

Comment: But this will not translate the date.